# Scrolling the end of tableView ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView)
{
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y >= (scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height))
    {
        print("test")//loadMoreData()
    }

}
```

In this code, I'm written to detect the tableView is scrolling until the end, then it will load more data, however it will execute many times as seen in the image of my console output, I just want execute one time after the end of tableView, how do I do that?
[image: Execute many times once I scroll until the end of tableView]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is a flag call you function only once on the base of the flag and change the value once call.But this is only works if you want to load more data only once.

```
if (scrollView.contentOffset.y >= (scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height))
    {
      if (!isLoaded)
         print("test")//loadMoreData()
      isLoaded = true
    }
```

Comment: thanks it works! I didnt think of this way, thank you!

Comment: Yes I mention but its a simple fix you can set to false again when data is loaded in loadMoreData().